# Hardfork - Pool Failed to parse block

Tags: mining-pools, hard-fork

I run a small pool with some friends on a fork of the cryptonote pool. I continue to receive "failed to parse block" errors after the hardfork and I cannot seem to figure out what to do. Last time I had this issue I changed the cryptonote-util library to the lucas jones one. However that doesn't seem to have updated or no longer works.

```
Error: Failed to parse block
at Object.BlockTemplate.nextBlob (/opt/pool2/lib/pool.js:120:23)
at Object.Miner.getJob (/opt/pool2/lib/pool.js:297:41)
at handleMinerMethod (/opt/pool2/lib/pool.js:497:28)
at handleMessage (/opt/pool2/lib/pool.js:611:13)
at Socket.socket.on.on.on.pushMessage (/opt/pool2/lib/pool.js:665:25)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything, run npm update, etc and I'm at a loss. I have the Wolfram Warptangent version of the node (full node!) and the wallet is also up-to-date.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
[This GitHub link](https://github.com/lucasjones/node-cryptonote-util/network) will show repos that have implemented the Ring CT changes. Scroll to the right. It isn't necessary to manually make the changes like I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pool update is needed for the last fork.
The patch is at https://paste.fedoraproject.org/506116/17116821/
There are updated trees which include this patch, but I do not have URLs handy.

After applying to the node-cryptonote-util tree, I think "npm rebuild" will be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

For linux Ubuntu:

1. in file package.json in pool root directory:

change string with "cryptonote-util" to:
"cryptonote-util": "git://github.com/moneromooo/node-cryptonote-util.git#rct"

2. run command in pool root directory:

rm -rf node_modules && npm update

3. run pool server again